# Apache : Redirecting with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to redirect local URL to point to production URL, however, I am not having much luck.

Here's what I have written in my .htaccess file,

```
RewriteRule "^http://local.production/sites/all/styles/(.*)$" "http://www.production.com/sites/all/styles/$1"
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [RewriteRule Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> In `Directory` and htaccess context, the *Pattern* will initially be
>   matched against the *filesystem path*, after removing the prefix that
>   led the server to the current `RewriteRule` (e.g. "app1/index.html" or
>   "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined). If you
>   wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a
>   [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or`%{QUERY_STRING}`
>   variables respectively.

So, this is probably what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.production$
RewriteRule "^sites/all/styles/(.*)$" "http://www.production.com/sites/all/styles/$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
Redirect http://local.production/sites/all/styles/(.*)$  h http://www.production.com/sites/all/styles/$1
```

Refer: 
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file